# Need regular expression for the below phone number

Tags: regex

The number of digits for Mobile is 11.
The number of digits for Landline is 10

In terms of format, all begin with zero for domestic calls and there are four variations for the landline:

Mobile  :   
0XX-XXXX-XXXX (3-4-4) Always remains same 

Landline:   
0X-XXXX-XXXX  (2-4-4)
            0XX-XXX-XXXX  (3-3-4)
            0XXX-XX-XXXX  (4-2-4)
            0XXXX-X-XXXX  (5-1-4)

The third box always comes with 4 digits.

For the landline, therefore, the first two boxes always have 6 digits in total.

Comment: At the very least you can do a "brute force" solution: `0\d-\d{4}-\d{4}|0\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}...`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex

```
0\d-\d{4}-\d{4}|0\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}|0\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|0\d{4}-\d-\d{4}
```